# textarea broken words on ipad and iphone - bluetooth scanner barcode zebra

Tags: ipad, web, textarea, words

I've this problem: I've connected a bluetooth reader scanner to my iPad as emulator keyboard, when I try to read a barcode with focus on a `textarea`, it seems to break the words randomly.

This only on iPad and iPhone, on all browsers: Firefox, Chrome, Safari
but not on Android. But I've to work on Ipad.

**Output Reading on pc (value of textarea):**

```
FF0034DC3214E20336C30C37
FF0034DC3214E20236C30C37
FF0034DC321540C336C30C03
FF0034DC3214A53036C30C06
FF0034DC3215804936C30C32
FF0034DC321584F936C30C35
FF0034DC3215A45336C30C03
FF0034DC321540C536C30C35
FF0034DC321B2CB336C30C03
FF0034DC3214A4D936C30C34
FF0034DC321540C436C30C36
FF0034DC3215907136C30C35
```

**Output reading on iPad:**

```
FF0034D
C3214E20
336C30C37
FF0034DC3214E20236C30C37
FF00
34DC32
1540C336C30C03
FF0034DC
3214A53036C30C06
FF00
34DC3215804936C30C32
FF0034DC321584F936C30C35
FF0034DC
3215A45336C30C03
FF0034DC321540C536C30C35FF0034DC321B2CB336C30C03FF0034DC3214A4D936C30C34FF0034DC321540C436C30C36FF0034DC3215907136C30C35
```

The strange things is that on some website it works!
For example on "https://jsfiddle.net/", if I put cursor in tab "html" and begin the readings with scanner, it works fine (on the html of this tab there is a textarea and when you write something, a span is created.
I don't understand how it works).

Anyone had never have this problems before?